# I tried to add ratingbar in dialog but I have some issue in stars number

Tags: android, dialog

I have tried to adding rating bar which have stars to do rating, 
I want make the rate have 4 stars, but in my code I get more than 7 stars 
and when I tried to click on a star then appear double.. (for example: I click star 1 then display 2 stars selected)..

my Example:

[image: my Example:]

My Code:

```js
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {


   TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // Button1
        final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddHotelRate);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ShowDialog();
            }
        });

    }



    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final RatingBar rating = new RatingBar(this);
        rating.setMax(4);

        popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
        popDialog.setTitle("Add Rating: ");
        popDialog.setView(rating);

        // Button OK
        popDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        textView.setText(String.valueOf(rating.getProgress()));
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                })

                // Button Cancel
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        popDialog.create();
        popDialog.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Issue is because **RatingBar** width matches the parent view and it
>   creates stars irrespective of number of stars, **RatingBar** should
>   have width as **wrap_content** respect to the parent.

Try placing **RatingBar** inside **LinearLayout** and add LinearLayout to your popup Dialog.

```
public void ShowDialog()
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    final RatingBar rating = new RatingBar(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    rating.setLayoutParams(lp);
    rating.setNumStars(4);
    rating.setStepSize(1);

    //add ratingBar to linearLayout
    linearLayout.addView(rating);


    popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
    popDialog.setTitle("Add Rating: ");

    //add linearLayout to dailog
    popDialog.setView(linearLayout);



    rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
            System.out.println("Rated val:"+v);
        }
    });



    // Button OK
    popDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(rating.getProgress()));
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            })

            // Button Cancel
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    popDialog.create();
    popDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your xml layout give

Height is `wrap_content`

Widhth is also `wrap_content`

And set `numStars`

You need use like this

```
final RatingBar rating = new RatingBar(this);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
 rating.setLayoutParams(lp);
 rating.setNumStars(4);
```

The same issue solve through the xml, try like this

```
   <RatingBar 
 enter code hereandroid:id="@+id/ratingBar"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:numStars="4" android:stepSize="1.0"
 android:rating="2.0" />
```

Then it will work...

For more information

https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html&grqid=wuehy0Mb&hl=en-IN

https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is useful if I have custom RatingBar but I add it in the dialog from Activity(new RatingBar...).. but I do some changed and its work now..

Answer (score 0):

Use `rating.setNumStars(4);` instead of `rating.setMax(4);`

Comment: I am sorry, But nothing changed!! :(

Answer (score 0):

**RateThisApp.java**

```
public class RateThisApp {

private static final String TAG = RateThisApp.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String PREF_NAME = "RateThisApp";
private static final String KEY_INSTALL_DATE = "rta_install_date";
private static final String KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES = "rta_launch_times";
private static final String KEY_OPT_OUT = "rta_opt_out";
private static final String KEY_ASK_LATER_DATE = "rta_ask_later_date";

private static Date mInstallDate = new Date();
private static int mLaunchTimes = 0;
private static boolean mOptOut = false;
private static Date mAskLaterDate = new Date();

private static Config sConfig = new Config();
private static Callback sCallback = null;
// Weak ref to avoid leaking the context
private static WeakReference<AlertDialog> sDialogRef = null;

/**
 * If true, print LogCat
 */
public static final boolean DEBUG = false;

/**
 * Initialize RateThisApp configuration.
 * @param config Configuration object.
 */
public static void init(Config config) {
    sConfig = config;
}

/**
 * Set callback instance.
 * The callback will receive yes/no/later events.
 * @param callback
 */
public static void setCallback(Callback callback) {
    sCallback = callback;
}

/**
 * Call this API when the launcher activity is launched.<br>
 * It is better to call this API in onCreate() of the launcher activity.
 * @param context Context
 */
public static void onCreate(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    // If it is the first launch, save the date in shared preference.
    if (pref.getLong(KEY_INSTALL_DATE, 0) == 0L) {
        storeInstallDate(context, editor);
    }
    // Increment launch times
    int launchTimes = pref.getInt(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES, 0);
    launchTimes++;
    editor.putInt(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES, launchTimes);
    log("Launch times; " + launchTimes);

    editor.apply();

    mInstallDate = new Date(pref.getLong(KEY_INSTALL_DATE, 0));
    mLaunchTimes = pref.getInt(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES, 0);
    mOptOut = pref.getBoolean(KEY_OPT_OUT, false);
    mAskLaterDate = new Date(pref.getLong(KEY_ASK_LATER_DATE, 0));

    printStatus(context);
}

/**
 * This API is deprecated.
 * You should call onCreate instead of this API in Activity's onCreate().
 * @param context
 */
@Deprecated
public static void onStart(Context context) {
    onCreate(context);
}

/**
 * Show the rate dialog if the criteria is satisfied.
 * @param context Context
 * @return true if shown, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean showRateDialogIfNeeded(final Context context) {
    if (shouldShowRateDialog()) {
        showRateDialog(context);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Show the rate dialog if the criteria is satisfied.
 * @param context Context
 * @param themeId Theme ID
 * @return true if shown, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean showRateDialogIfNeeded(final Context context, int themeId) {
    if (shouldShowRateDialog()) {
        showRateDialog(context, themeId);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Check whether the rate dialog should be shown or not.
 * Developers may call this method directly if they want to show their own view instead of
 * dialog provided by this library.
 * @return
 */
public static boolean shouldShowRateDialog() {
    if (mOptOut) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (mLaunchTimes >= sConfig.mCriteriaLaunchTimes) {
            return true;
        }
        long threshold = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(sConfig.mCriteriaInstallDays);   // msec
        if (new Date().getTime() - mInstallDate.getTime() >= threshold &&
            new Date().getTime() - mAskLaterDate.getTime() >= threshold) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Show the rate dialog
 * @param context
 */
public static void showRateDialog(final Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    showRateDialog(context, builder);
}

/**
 * Show the rate dialog
 * @param context
 * @param themeId
 */
public static void showRateDialog(final Context context, int themeId) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, themeId);
    showRateDialog(context, builder);
}

/**
 * Stop showing the rate dialog
 * @param context
 */
public static void stopRateDialog(final Context context){
    setOptOut(context, true);
}

/**
 * Get count number of the rate dialog launches
 * @return
 */
public static int getLaunchCount(final Context context){
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getInt(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES, 0);
}

private static void showRateDialog(final Context context, AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
    if (sDialogRef != null && sDialogRef.get() != null) {
        // Dialog is already present
        return;
    }

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    final RatingBar rating = new RatingBar(context);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    rating.setLayoutParams(lp);
    rating.setNumStars(5);
    rating.setStepSize(1);
    rating.setRating(5);

    //add ratingBar to linearLayout
    linearLayout.addView(rating);

    int titleId = sConfig.mTitleId != 0 ? sConfig.mTitleId :R.string.app_name;
    int messageId = sConfig.mMessageId != 0 ? sConfig.mMessageId : R.string.my_own_message;
    int cancelButtonID = sConfig.mCancelButton != 0 ? sConfig.mCancelButton : R.string.my_own_cancel;
    int thanksButtonID = sConfig.mNoButtonId != 0 ? sConfig.mNoButtonId : R.string.my_own_thanks;
    int rateButtonID = sConfig.mYesButtonId != 0 ? sConfig.mYesButtonId : R.string.my_own_rate;
    builder.setTitle(titleId);
    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setMessage(messageId);
    builder.setCancelable(sConfig.mCancelable);
    builder.setView(linearLayout);
    builder.setPositiveButton(rateButtonID, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (sCallback != null) {
                sCallback.onYesClicked();
            }
            String appPackage = context.getPackageName();
            String url = "market://details?id=" + appPackage;
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sConfig.mUrl)) {
                url = sConfig.mUrl;
            }
            try {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.getPackageName())));
            }
            setOptOut(context, true);
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton(cancelButtonID, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (sCallback != null) {
                sCallback.onCancelClicked();
            }
            clearSharedPreferences(context);
            storeAskLaterDate(context);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(thanksButtonID, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (sCallback != null) {
                sCallback.onNoClicked();
            }
            setOptOut(context, true);
        }
    });
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if (sCallback != null) {
                sCallback.onCancelClicked();
            }
            clearSharedPreferences(context);
            storeAskLaterDate(context);
        }
    });
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            sDialogRef.clear();
        }
    });
    sDialogRef = new WeakReference<>(builder.show());
}

/**
 * Clear data in shared preferences.<br>
 * This API is called when the "Later" is pressed or canceled.
 * @param context
 */
private static void clearSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.remove(KEY_INSTALL_DATE);
    editor.remove(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES);
    editor.apply();
}

/**
 * Set opt out flag.
 * If it is true, the rate dialog will never shown unless app data is cleared.
 * This method is called when Yes or No is pressed.
 * @param context
 * @param optOut
 */
private static void setOptOut(final Context context, boolean optOut) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(KEY_OPT_OUT, optOut);
    editor.apply();
    mOptOut = optOut;
}

/**
 * Store install date.
 * Install date is retrieved from package manager if possible.
 * @param context
 * @param editor
 */
private static void storeInstallDate(final Context context, SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
    Date installDate = new Date();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        PackageManager packMan = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            PackageInfo pkgInfo = packMan.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            installDate = new Date(pkgInfo.firstInstallTime);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    editor.putLong(KEY_INSTALL_DATE, installDate.getTime());
    log("First install: " + installDate.toString());
}

/**
 * Store the date the user asked for being asked again later.
 * @param context
 */
private static void storeAskLaterDate(final Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putLong(KEY_ASK_LATER_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
    editor.apply();
}

/**
 * Print values in SharedPreferences (used for debug)
 * @param context
 */
private static void printStatus(final Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    log("*** RateThisApp Status ***");
    log("Install Date: " + new Date(pref.getLong(KEY_INSTALL_DATE, 0)));
    log("Launch Times: " + pref.getInt(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES, 0));
    log("Opt out: " + pref.getBoolean(KEY_OPT_OUT, false));
}

/**
 * Print log if enabled
 * @param message
 */
private static void log(String message) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.v(TAG, message);
    }
}

/**
 * RateThisApp configuration.
 */
public static class Config {
    private String mUrl = null;
    private int mCriteriaInstallDays;
    private int mCriteriaLaunchTimes;
    private int mTitleId = 0;
    private int mMessageId = 0;
    private int mYesButtonId = 0;
    private int mNoButtonId = 0;
    private int mCancelButton = 0;
    private boolean mCancelable = true;

    /**
     * Constructor with default criteria.
     */
    public Config() {
        this(7, 10);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param criteriaInstallDays
     * @param criteriaLaunchTimes
     */
    public Config(int criteriaInstallDays, int criteriaLaunchTimes) {
        this.mCriteriaInstallDays = criteriaInstallDays;
        this.mCriteriaLaunchTimes = criteriaLaunchTimes;
    }

    /**
     * Set title string ID.
     * @param stringId
     */
    public void setTitle(@StringRes int stringId) {
        this.mTitleId = stringId;
    }

    /**
     * Set message string ID.
     * @param stringId
     */
    public void setMessage(@StringRes int stringId) {
        this.mMessageId = stringId;
    }

    /**
     * Set rate now string ID.
     * @param stringId
     */
    public void setYesButtonText(@StringRes int stringId) {
        this.mYesButtonId = stringId;
    }

    /**
     * Set no thanks string ID.
     * @param stringId
     */
    public void setNoButtonText(@StringRes int stringId) {
        this.mNoButtonId = stringId;
    }

    /**
     * Set cancel string ID.
     * @param stringId
     */
    public void setCancelButtonText(@StringRes int stringId) {
        this.mCancelButton = stringId;
    }

    /**
     * Set navigation url when user clicks rate button.
     * Typically, url will be https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=PACKAGE_NAME for Google Play.
     * @param url
     */
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.mUrl = url;
    }

    public void setCancelable(boolean cancelable) {
        this.mCancelable = cancelable;
    }
}

/**
 * Callback of dialog click event
 */
public interface Callback {
    /**
     * "Rate now" event
     */
    void onYesClicked();

    /**
     * "No, thanks" event
     */
    void onNoClicked();

    /**
     * "Later" event
     */
    void onCancelClicked();
}
```

}

*After Simply Call*

```
RateThisApp.Config config = new RateThisApp.Config(0, 0);
    config.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    config.setMessage(R.string.my_own_message);
    config.setYesButtonText(R.string.my_own_rate);
    config.setNoButtonText(R.string.my_own_thanks);
    config.setCancelButtonText(R.string.my_own_cancel);
    RateThisApp.init(config);

    // Monitor launch times and interval from installation
    RateThisApp.onCreate(mContext);
    // If the condition is satisfied, "Rate this app" dialog will be shown
    RateThisApp.showRateDialog(mContext);


    RateThisApp.setCallback(new RateThisApp.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onYesClicked() {

           // mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
            RateThisApp.stopRateDialog(mContext);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNoClicked() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (editor != null) {
                editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            RateThisApp.stopRateDialog(mContext);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelClicked() {
            RateThisApp.stopRateDialog(mContext);
        }
    });
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]